# Convert Flask-based API to AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I currently have an AWS EC2 instance exposing a Flask API with blueprints running different things on different ports. I am wondering which is the bast solution architecture-wise in order to convert the endpoint to Lambda. For instance, should I remove the blueprints? If so, how can I call the different functionalities on the different pots?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the python package that you can use to deploy your flask application to AWS lambda with minimal configurations

https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa

Comment: Note that Zappa is no longer maintained. Another alternative for Python and Lambda generally is [AWS Chalice](https://github.com/aws/chalice) though it is not optimized for Flask apps afaik.

Comment: Chalice is an entirely different library and it's meant to deploy code to was lambda and we can use multiple other AWS features in it, whereas using Zappa you can deploy complete Django or flask app as it is. keeping the fact that it's no longer maintained. thanks for pointing this out.